# What is the function that describes this Asymptotic behaviour

Tags: functions, asymptotics

I would like to find a function such that for

$$a(x) \rightarrow 1~\text{for}~(x \gg x_c)$$

$$a(x) \rightarrow f(x)~\text{for}~(x \ll x_c)$$

What could be the $a(x)$ ? I have tried some simple functions but could not figure it out. Maybe I am just blind to see the correct result.

Comment: Why not $a(x) = 1$ for $x\ge x_c$ and $a(x) = f(x)$ for $x<x_c$?

Comment: Thats also okay I guess...

Comment: Your asymptotic properties leave a large range of values where $a(x)$ could be anything. You will have to put more conditions on $a(x)$ in that range to get something you like the look of.

Comment: What if I say, finding simplest possible $a(x)$. Is that makes sense ? Of course there could be infinetly many functions, but I am looking for least complicated/simplest one

Comment: Probably the one I gave, though it will not be continuous at $x_c$ unless $f(x_c) = 1$ (assuming it can be defined at $x_c$). Simple is subjective, it just depends what you want $a(x)$ to look like between the two asymptotic end values.

Comment: No, I am looking for one single function, I mean. When I take the asymptotic behavior, it produces the results I have mentioned.

Comment: Simplest is hard to define... continuous? Non singular? Elementary? In any case, a well behaved monotonic example is $a(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{x_c}f(x)}{e^x+e^{x_c}}$

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have found. It seems the answer is

For $$a(x) = \frac{f(x)x_c - x}{x_c - x}$$

$$a(x) = 1~\text{for}~x \gg x_c$$

$$a(x) = f(x)~\text{for}~x \ll x_c$$

Comment: Good luck to you in your further endeavors.